# Crashplan on headless server

Tags: 11.10, headless, crashplan

I've Googled a bit and not really found anything out. I want to install Crashplan for remote upload on Crashplan+. How painless is the installation and set up?

Crashplans site is lacking a lot of information from what I've looked at.

The server is headless and while it has GNOME installed, it's not used. So I need something completely console driven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work http://nerdwa.com/index.php/2011/05/crashplan-on-ubuntu-server/

There's some stuff at the end about editing the client on a mac but the first 2 commands are for Ubuntu installation and likely all you need

Comment: Dead link. Last functioning snapshot from the Wayback machine:  http://web.archive.org/web/20120404065030/http://nerdwa.com/index.php/2011/05/crashplan-on-ubuntu-server/

Answer (score 1):

As long as your usage on that server will be Set & Forget.  You will find it very difficult to tweak CrashPlan settings without occasional GUI interaction.  I have VNC access to mine for the occasional session - I find I am in there once or twice a month either checking on things or changing something.

You'll find that all the more important if your server is going to be the local backup destination as well as a client for the cloud service.  If it's only the latter, you may indeed be Set & Forget in which case Meddy's answer is ALL you need.

Comment: Good point, I SSH in tunelling X11 and just run CrashPlanDesktop